# SqlDataReader GetDecimal without .00

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm wondering how can I read with my `SqlDataReader` data type numeric (9,2) without `.00`. Here is my code for reading it:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", conn);
                spojeni.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = comm .ExecuteReader();
textBox19.Text = reader .GetDecimal(22).ToString().Replace(',', '.');
}
```

Would you please tell me how should I improve this code to read it without .00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the value in your SQL Statement:

```
select *, cast(ColumnName as numeric(9,0)) as Alias from klient where ID_K=1
```

**Edit:**

I wouldnt use GetDecimal at all since I dont really like the idea of the overload having only an integer to pick, I personally think its better to read with the given columnnames.

So to fetch the data from the cast column I'd do the following:

```
decimal value = 0;
decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(reader["Alias"]), out value);
textBox19.Text = value.ToString();
```

This can be easily made into an extension of SqlDataReader like this:

```
public static decimal GetDecimal(this SqlDataReader reader, string columnName)
{
    decimal value = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(reader[columnName]), out value);
    return value;
}
```

And than just call the following:

```
textBox19.Text = precti.GetDecimal("Alias").ToString();
```

**Edit 2:**

Something just came into my mind that maybe is more to your liking. 
Insted of doing a cast threw the SQL Statement you could just simply format your decimal numer the way you want it to, with the following code:

```
textBox19.Text = string.Format("{0:n0}", precti.GetDecimal(22));
```

"{0:n0}" will result in a numeric value with 0 position after decimal point.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, is there way to improve the read command? Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you can further explain what you mean with "improve the read command", I may can help out.

Comment: I mean this line of code: textBox19.Text = precti.GetDecimal(22).ToString().Replace(',', '.');

Comment: Thank you so much, is there way to make it without the free space? now it is like 1 123 instead of 1123

Comment: What solution are you using?

Comment: textBox19.Text = string.Format("{0:n0}", precti.GetDecimal(22)); :)

Comment: change the n to d, n will result to being formatted like the culture says so when the thousand splitter is a dot it would be -
1.123 with d you are ignoring this and and just display a regular number without the format.

so:
textBox19.Text = string.Format("{0:d0}", precti.GetDecimal(22)); 

a nice little page about format is here:
http://alexonasp.net/samples/stringformatting/

Comment: Oh I tried that but it thrown an ex so 0:0 works well for me, thank you again for your time, have a nice day !

Comment: A little advertisment: you should get resharper its intellisense would give you the string format possibilities. :)

And thanks for telling me that d, doesnt work in combination with digits. Never used it before and I dont really get why it should throw an error, but as you already figured you can always use the placeholders 0 or # to do something like this.

If you want to have the result (no formatting) but this time with the decimal precision you would do the following: "{0:0.00}" for 2 precision.